# When upvoting can we consider pedagogical even if it didn't answer the question correctly?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, upvotes

I have come across folks who tend to downvote something just because it didn't answer the question directly and to the point, but nevertheless was on-topic and very informative. I prefer to not vote at all in this case.

But I tend to upvote if it was useful to me even if it may not have answered the question per se.

What is SO's or the general population's perception on this ?

Comment: The tooltip says *"This answer is useful"* - beyond that, let your conscience be your guide!

Comment: Yes the interesting thing is that an answer can be both useful and not useful (or useful but unclear etc).  So any voting decision is understandable.  It all depends on what you think is the most important.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, please see my response to BSMP

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

> How do I write a good answer?
>
> ...
>
> **Answer the question**
>
> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question
>   asking for? **Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable
>   alternative.** The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also
>   include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in
>   the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations,
>   assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable,
>   but fuller explanations are better.

Emphasis mine.

I suppose *Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful* might provide some wiggle room but, in my opinion, if it doesn't answer the question then it's not an answer.

That said, it's not clear what you mean by "may not have answered the question per se". Are you thinking of times that someone suggested an alternative to what the Asker was trying to do (which is an answer), do you mean something more like someone suggesting debugging strategies, or do you mean something like the question is about a problem with a pointer and the answer is a tutorial on pointers (should be a comment)?

Comment: Just the fact that an answer (actually it should be renamed 'Response') is being upvoted does NOT mean it IS the right answer. It is upto the OP to select the right answer. We can appreciate the breakthroughs that SO has made into coercing proper answers but this is going too far. Why try to bludgeon useful info ? You don't like this page to be hit when someone queries the exact words in a useful-but-not-an-answer response ? IMO that's pretty anal.

Comment: @killjoy Your question asks, _What is SO's or the general population's perception on this?_ I am quoting directly from SO's help page on "How to Answer". This, "Why try to bludgeon useful info?", is a strawman argument. I never said not to post useful info, I said that if it doesn't actually answer the question, then it's not an Answer.

Comment: @killjoy, it should not be renamed "Response", because it's not that; it's  an _answer_. A solution to your problem. That may be the most fundamental point of the Stack Overflow model: you ask a **question**, and get **answers**. Not replies, responses, and discussion. If you want those, use different software.

Answer (score -6):

I might have a different skew/view of things, but I upvote mostly everyone who has contributed to the help of my question(?s). And ofcourse, if I believe they put effort in their post.

That effort is subjective and can be detrimental. Sometimes, the good ol' smart Javascript dev will pop in once in a while and answer your question in less than 20 seconds.  Especially lets say if it was a question you were having trouble with for months. [My Example Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155812/how-do-i-grab-the-offsetx-of-the-parent-div).

**Do not brush** them off as not putting any effort in to help your question because they posted so fast.  But instead, sit back and let it soak in that your problem is actually now fixed, and yes, they're people who are smarter than us. Learn from them, and upvote them.

Comment: There's no "effort" in the voting tooltip for a reason: It has nothing to do with the quality of the post.

Comment: It's pretty sadistic of you to knowingly lie to future readers of the post about it's quality by upvoting low quality content, potentially resulting in them thinking that the broken or even actively harmful answer that you've upvoted is actually a useful or quality solution to the problem.  I mean I'm all for the occasional practical joke and all, but that's pretty much just *cruel* for the sake of cruelty.

Comment: @Servy That esculated quickly, no idea what you're talking about. There is no joke here. Look at all my past questions I upvote people all the time if they are WILLING to help me regardless of their knowledge, that's my point. If you find that sadistic, not sure what to tell you. I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: People shouldn't get upvotes just for participating in a question

Comment: If they are participating in a quest that helps me get my problem/question solved, they are getting an upvote. That's my view on it anyway.

Comment: @NiCkNewman You see nothing wrong with lying to people and telling them that incorrect/harmful/bad/etc. answers are actually quality answers?

Comment: @NiCkNewman So, what, you just don't care about anyone in the world besides yourself?  As long as you benefit you don't care what happens to anyone else?  And you think this is a constructive viewpoint?

Comment: @Servy That's why we have the accepted answer button... I use it for that very reason..

Comment: @NiCkNewman No, that's why we have votes.  To indicate the quality of the posts, not to give them to literally everyone no matter what and thus make a posts score 100% useless (in the best case) to any future reader.

Comment: I can see your point, but if a post contains code and it seems to me the user is trying to help.. I will upvote them? If the code is legible ofcourse. Then, if a user posts code that solved my problem, I will upvote them and then mark them as correct answer. So you're telling me I shouldn't give out reputation to people who are trying to help me? To me, that seems rude and feels like I'm taking advantage of the system.

Comment: @NiCk, that is exactly my reasoning too. This Servy guy seems to take it to an extreme with assuming we are being sadistic. That is as stupid as some of the most useful questions on SO being 'closed as unconstuctive' or idiots who downvote real useful related info which doesnt directly answer the question. There are some people who will add a 'just for your info' comment or answer. It is UPTO the OP to decide which the best answer is. So why the heck would the others get their panties in a wad for additional comments on the topic ? Such attitude will surely lead to the downfall of SO.

Comment: Yes, @NiCkNewman, you shouldn't hand out upvotes for trying. You should upvote answers that are useful and clear solutions to the problem expressed in the question.